# SQL: Query does not return duplicates correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014 Express.

I have a table consisting of information about various professional fights. I have assigned my own Fight ID to each row.

Sometimes, information about the same fight is recorded multiple times, using different Fight IDs. My goal is to identify these duplicates, and then delete them from my table.

This is the code for creating my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fights](
    [FightId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LowIdFighter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HighIdFighter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LowIdFighterOutcome] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [EventName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [WinningMethod] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Referee] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FinishingRound] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FinishingTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Fights] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FightId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    LowIdFighter, HighIdFighter, CAST(EventDate AS DATE),
    LowIdFighterOutcome,
    COUNT(*) as NumTimesSaved
INTO Duplicate_Fights
FROM Fights
GROUP BY 
    LowIdFighter, HighIdFighter, EventDate, 
    LowIdFighterOutcome
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
GO
```

My problem is this: The table Duplicate_Fights contains fights that are not actually duplicates. Fights are considered to be duplicates insofar as they share the same values in *any* two of the four columns (LowIdFighter, HighIdFighter, EventDate, LowIdFighterOutcome). E.g., two fights are considered to be duplicates of each other if they share the same LowIdFighter-HighIdFighter pair, even if these two fighters fought at two completely separate events, possibly with two completely different outcomes. Obviously, this is not what I want.

I want to write a query expression that returns a table of duplicate fights which share the same values in *all* of the four columns. I would appreciate any help on the matter. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the output when I exclude the "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" statement:

[image]

Row 149 and Row 150 are *not* duplicates of each other, because the dates in those two rows are different, and yet they are included the table of duplicate fights.

Comment: This is exactly what your query is supposed to return, rows where all four columns are exactly the same. The only thing you might change is use `CAST(EventDate AS DATE)`  in the `
GROUP BY`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two rows are not duplicate of each other, but both of them exist twice, i.e. fighter `45386` had two fights and both were inserted twice.

Answer (score 1):

I am just trying to help.

Your query should work, as suggested by *dnoeth*,but just make sure that you use exactly the *same attribute*(or its manipulation) in the *GROUP BY clause* as you use to retrieve column (*in Select clause*) as below:

```
SELECT 
    LowIdFighter, HighIdFighter, CAST(EventDate AS DATE),
    LowIdFighterOutcome,
    COUNT(*) as NumTimesSaved
INTO Duplicate_Fights
FROM Fights
GROUP BY 
    LowIdFighter, HighIdFighter, CAST(EventDate AS DATE), 
    LowIdFighterOutcome
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
GO
```